# How to emit message from client side [node.js + socket.io]

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to emit message from client side with socket.io ...

Here is my client code:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/');
          socket.on('connect', function(data){
                setStatus('connected');
                socket.emit('subscribe', {channel:'update.comment'});
            });
```

Server:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', { text : 'Welcome!' });
  socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
    socket.join(data.channel);
    redisClient.subscribe(data.channel);
  });
});
```

Also I get this error message in console:

> GET
>   http://localhost/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1442169984269-1
>   404 (Not Found)

Full serever:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var redis = require('ioredis');
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

redisClient = redis.createClient();

//look for connection errors and log
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("error event - " + redisClient.host + ":" + redisClient.port + " - " + err);
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('message', { text : 'Welcome!' });
  //on subscription request joins specified room
  //later messages are broadcasted on the rooms
  socket.on('subscribe', function (data) {
    socket.join(data.channel);
    redisClient.subscribe(data.channel);
  });
});

redisClient.on('ready', function(data) {
  console.log('#redis ready');
});

redisClient.on("message", function(channel, message){
    console.log(channel);
    var resp = {'text': message, 'channel':channel};
    io.sockets.in(channel).emit('message', resp);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**New Problem Recognized:**

Your server is listening on port 3000, but you are attempting to connect on port 80.  The error message `http://localhost/socket.io?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1442169984269-1` has no port number on it so that defaults to port 80.

---

That error message means that your server-side socket.io code is not initialized  correctly and thus is not listening for the HTTP request that starts all webSocket connections so when the browser tries to connect on that URL to initiate a socket.io connection, there's nobody on the server-side listening so the web server returns a 404 error back to the browser.

If you are using Express, this is the minimal socket.io initialization to hook it into your server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8081);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

For a plain HTTP server, this is the minimal socket.io initialization:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
app.listen(80);
```

As always, if you show us the socket.io and web server initialization code you are using, we can help you better with your specific code issue.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic - yes, that's because when your browser tries to make the socket.io connection, it finds that the server is NOT listening for the URL that socket.io uses to initiate a socket.io connection.  Your browser is telling you that no server is listening for that URL.  You need to fix that issue on the server.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic - As you can see by [this similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491737/where-is-my-client-side-socket-io/32492775#32492775) from a few days ago, that socket.io initialization sequence you are using does not appear to work, but the one I've suggested does.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic - see the additional thing I see in your code at the beginning of my answer about using the wrong port.